# How to get source of custom meta image?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta, images

I'm working on a CPT (custom post type) page template and would like to get the source of custom meta image.

For post_thumbnail's this is rather easy using `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`, but if I `var_dump( $post->ID )` I don't see a value for my custom meta attachment image source.

So how can I get the ID of my custom-meta-image to get it's source? Thanks :)

UPDATE This is what I got going.

```
<?php $portfolio_image_one = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_portfolio_image_one', true ); ?>
<?php $portfolio_image_two = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_portfolio_image_two', true ); ?>
<?php $portfolio_image_three = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_portfolio_image_three', true ); ?>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
$large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); ?>
<a class="featured-image" href="<?php echo $large_image_url[0] ?>" title="' . <?php the_title_attribute('echo=0') ?> . '">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'img-polaroid')); ?>
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Basically, I would like to get the ID for my post_meta images in a similar way to the thumbnail approach.

Comment: What matters is what you're storing in the custom field, not how you're getting it. It's common to store the ID for images, but I'm guess you aren't doing that. What _are_ you storing in the meta fields?

Comment: Not the ID :), I was hoping not having to do that manually. I found a couple of ways by matching $wpdb fields. But I also found a better way not using the IDs at all. If I find some time I'll post what I found out.

Answer (score 3):

Custom Meta Image? What's that?

Do you mean that,

- you are inserting an image into a custom field (post meta field) within your meta box?
- you are inserting an image as a post attachment or thumbnail?

These are two very different *things* one of which is dealing with,

```
add_post_meta
```

the other,

```
wp_insert_attachment
```

The latter of which inserts attachments into your media library which is associated with your `wp_posts` database table.

Post meta on the other hand (i.e. `add_post_meta` etc) is associated with your `wp_postmeta'` database table.

**Attachments** are actually classified as a `post_type` just line `post` or `page` or your `custom_post_type` for instance.

**Attachments**, as a post type, may or may not also then be associated with a Post's ID, stored as an integer in the `post_parent` column in your `wp_posts` database. If set to `0`, this means that the attachment has no parent and is not associated with any particular post.

## Theory aside...

You may very well be trying to access an attachment that simply doesn't exist in the first place.

```
$attachment_id = 20; //example ID of the attachment you want to retrieve
$attachment = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );
echo $attachment[0];
```

The particular code above is useful for retrieving an attachment which is not associated with any particular post.

```
$post_id = 100; //example post ID
$attachment = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $post_id );
echo $attachment; //returns the URL of the image attached to the post
```

Where as retrieving an value, regardless of what that value is, when dealing with post meta (as you referred to as ***custom meta image***) requires the use of,

```
get_post_meta
```

In use,

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'your_meta_key');
echo $meta;
```

## API References

- [WordPress API: add_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta)
- [WordPress API: wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)
- [WordPress API: wp_get_attachment_thumb_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_thumb_url)
- [WordPress API: wp_insert_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)
- [WordPress API: get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

## UPDATE

Based on your code,

```
$portfolio_image_one = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_portfolio_image_one', true );
```

The post_meta value is held within your variable,

```
$portfolio_image_one
```

What you need to do is,

```
echo $portfolio_image_one;
```

Otherwise nothing is going to happen.

If there is a value stored for the `meta_key` i.e. `_cmb_portfolio_image_one` then by echoing the result of the variable, you shall be presented with your `meta_value` whatever that value is, such as `http://domain.com/my_image.jpg` for example.

If $post->ID is being used outside of the loop you will run into trouble, hence refer to my previous example, but with your code,

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$portfolio_image_one = get_post_meta($post_id, '_cmb_portfolio_image_one', true);
echo $portfolio_image_one;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the elaborate reply, unfortunately it doesn't answer my question. I'll update my post to show you what I'm working with.

Comment: 'get_post_meta($post_id, '_cmb_portfolio_image_one', true);' is returning the full image url. how will you get the 'medium' size url for example?